# NUnit Test Domain events

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-events

I used this for implementation domain events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation

I have event, handle and transaction infrastructure for dispatch event. But how can I write tests for handler? How can I call handler from unit test without "savecontenxt() " which used in API for this.

for example event and handle

event

```
public class OrderStartedDomainEvent : INotification
{
    public string UserId { get; }
    public int CardTypeId { get; }
    public string CardNumber { get; }
    public string CardSecurityNumber { get; }
    public string CardHolderName { get; }
    public DateTime CardExpiration { get; }
    public Order Order { get; }

    public OrderStartedDomainEvent(Order order,
                                   int cardTypeId, string cardNumber,
                                   string cardSecurityNumber, string cardHolderName,
                                   DateTime cardExpiration)
    {
        Order = order;
        CardTypeId = cardTypeId;
        CardNumber = cardNumber;
        CardSecurityNumber = cardSecurityNumber;
        CardHolderName = cardHolderName;
        CardExpiration = cardExpiration;
    }
}
```

eventin entity

```
var orderStartedDomainEvent = new OrderStartedDomainEvent(this, //Order object
                                                          cardTypeId, cardNumber,
                                                          cardSecurityNumber,
                                                          cardHolderName,
                                                          cardExpiration);
this.AddDomainEvent(orderStartedDomainEvent);
```

handler

````
                   : INotificationHandler<OrderStartedDomainEvent>
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _logger;
    private readonly IBuyerRepository<Buyer> _buyerRepository;
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public ValidateOrAddBuyerAggregateWhenOrderStartedDomainEventHandler(
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        IBuyerRepository<Buyer> buyerRepository,
        IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        // ...Parameter validations...
    }

    public async Task Handle(OrderStartedDomainEvent orderStartedEvent)
    {
        var cardTypeId = (orderStartedEvent.CardTypeId != 0) ? orderStartedEvent.CardTypeId : 1;
        var userGuid = _identityService.GetUserIdentity();
        var buyer = await _buyerRepository.FindAsync(userGuid);
        bool buyerOriginallyExisted = (buyer == null) ? false : true;

        if (!buyerOriginallyExisted)
        {
            buyer = new Buyer(userGuid);
        }

        buyer.VerifyOrAddPaymentMethod(cardTypeId,
                                       $"Payment Method on {DateTime.UtcNow}",
                                       orderStartedEvent.CardNumber,
                                       orderStartedEvent.CardSecurityNumber,
                                       orderStartedEvent.CardHolderName,
                                       orderStartedEvent.CardExpiration,
                                       orderStartedEvent.Order.Id);

        var buyerUpdated = buyerOriginallyExisted ? _buyerRepository.Update(buyer)
                                                                      : _buyerRepository.Add(buyer);

        await _buyerRepository.UnitOfWork
                .SaveEntitiesAsync();

        // Logging code using buyerUpdated info, etc.
    }
}```
````

Comment: Where is the `SaveContext()`? Why can't you instantiate `ValidateOrAddBuyerAggregateWhenOrderStartedDomainEventHandler` in a unit test (with mock/fake dependencies)?

Comment: I mean SaveChanges(), sorry. EF savechanges need to call and match event and handler. Sure I can call handler but how do it correctly if the entity has a lot of events? using foreach like this?  foreach (var e in OrderStartedDomainEvent.DomainEvents)
   {
    if (e is OrderStartedDomainEvent ee)
     handler.Handle(ee, new CancellationToken());
   }

Comment: Your question was regarding `unit test`s right? This comment seems like you're asking about persisting events to the database (`EF`) for an `Entity`, so I'm a bit confused towards what you're asking.
Could you clear up your question, stating what it is you want answered and including *only* relevant information?

Comment: I'm asking about unit test, and said that SaveChanges() using in API for match handler with event, but I don't know how match my handler with event in unit test correctly , maybe like I wrote before - "foreach (var e in OrderStartedDomainEvent.DomainEvents) { if (e is OrderStartedDomainEvent ee) handler.Handle(ee, new CancellationToken()); } "

Comment: What dou you mean by `"how match my handler with event in unit test"`? If you have a `unit test` where you create a `ValidateOrAddBuyerAggregateWhenOrderStartedDomainEventHandler` (with mock dependencies - you could use `Moq` for this) and call the `Handle` method with a `OrderStartedDomainEvent`, can't you then test what you want to test?
Otherwise I need some more information on what you want to test.